# How to convert this query to MySQL from MSSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

How to convert this query to MySQL from MSSQL?

Query:

```
SELECT count(id) AS counter, 
        SUBSTRING(user_name, CHARINDEX('@', user_name) + 1, LEN(user_name)) AS domain, 
        comp_id 
FROM user_stat 
WHERE ok='y'  
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(user_name, CHARINDEX('@', user_name) + 1, LEN(user_name)), 
        comp_id  
ORDER BY counter DESC
```

Mostly this part is what i care:

```
SUBSTRING(user_name, CHARINDEX('@', user_name) + 1, LEN(user_name)) AS domain
```

I can not find solution for this. ..
Thanks in advance!

Comment: MySQL does have a user manual, it contains a miriad of useful information like all the STRING Processing Function that MySQL provides. [Why not read it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to change `LEN` with `LENGTH` and `CHARINDEX` with `LOCATE`:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/functions.html

```
SELECT count(id) AS counter, 
        SUBSTRING(user_name, LOCATE('@', user_name) + 1, LENGTH(user_name)) AS domain, 
        comp_id 
FROM user_stat 
WHERE ok='y'  
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(user_name, LOCATE('@', user_name) + 1, LENGTH(user_name)), 
        comp_id  
ORDER BY counter DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining! It seems it did work!

Answer (score 0):

```
SUBSTRING(user_name, LOCATE('@', user_name) + 1) AS domain
```